# DevExpress C# grid view doesn't display data

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress-windows-ui

I want to display some data in the gridView1 from a list but it won't show the data just the header row. I created a datasource object `Transakcija` and selected it as a data source for the gridControl but it just doesn't display the actual data.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<Transakcija> list1 = new List<Transakcija>();
        
        list1.Add(new Transakcija
        {
            TrnType = "1",
            IzvodBroj = "2",
            NovoStanje = "3",
            PrethodnoStanje = "4",
            FitID = "5",
            TrnUID = "6",
            Benefit = "7",
            NazivPrimaoca = "8",
            Grad = "9",
            Racun = "10",
            BankID = "11",
            Banka = "12",
            Datum = "13",
            Iznos = "14",
            SvrhaPlacanja = "15",
            Sifra = "16",
            Valuta = "17",
            PayeeRefNumber = "18",
            TrnPlace = "19",
            DtUser = "20",
            DtAvail = "21",
            RefNumber = "22",
            RefModel = "23",
            PayeeRefModel = "24",
            Urgency = "25",
            Naknada = "26",
            StatusCode = "27",
            StatusTimePosted = "28",
            RacunBanke = "29"
        });

        gridControl1.DataSource = new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<Transakcija>(list1);
        gridControl1.Refresh();

}
```

I tried looking at the properties of the grid control but I didn't find why it doesn't display it.

Comment: Try it this way: BindingList<Transakcija> list1 = new BindingList<Transakcija>(); list1.Add(new Transakcija(){...}); gridControl1.DataSource = list1;

Comment: Please can you add the definition of the class `Transakcija` and show how the Columns are added to the Grid.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I have a potential solution for you (its a best guess as you haven't provided the definition of the class `Transakcija` or shown how the columns are defined or added to the GridControl/GridView).

There are also other considerations such as setting the [FieldName](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.FieldName) of the [GridColumn](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn).

I found that it depends on how your class `Transakcija` is defined.

If the members `TrnType`, `IzvodBroj`, `NovoStanje`, etc are defined as [Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) then it won't work. They need to be defined as [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

This does not work

> ```
> internal class Transakcija
> {
>     public String TrnType;
>     public String IzvodBroj;
>     public String NovoStanje;
> }
> ```

This does work:

```
internal class Transakcija
{
    public String TrnType { get; set; }
    public String IzvodBroj { get; set; }
    public String NovoStanje { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is my class Transakcija
<code>
namespace DXApplication1
{
    public class Transakcija
    {
        public string TrnType { get; set; }
        public string IzvodBroj { get; set;}
        public string NovoStanje { get; set; }
        ...


    }
}
<code>

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue the code was ok but I had to reselect the data source object again in the GUI part probably was an old object before rebuilding the project.